# How can overflow be defined for the Klein bottle in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, intersection-theory, klein-bottle

I was watching Dr. Tadashi Tokeida's lecture series on Youtube:
https://kevinbinz.com/2017/10/25/isotopy/

For submanifolds $L$ and $K$ being placed in ambient manifold $M$, the overflow can be defined as:
$$
\mathbb{o} = (\dim L + \dim K) - \dim M
$$

In the case of the Klein bottle can we say because there is only one two-dimensional submanifold inside $\mathbb{R}^3$, the overflow would be:
$$
-1 = (2) - 3 \qquad (?)
$$

Or since the Klein bottle self-intersecting a curve on the plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the overflow should be written as this:
$$
1 = (2 + 2) - 3 \qquad (?)
$$

In the former case, there is no self-intersection in $\mathbb{R^4}$ and crossing is possible, because $\mathbb{o}<-1$, but in the latter, there is still a self-intersection at a point in $\mathbb{R}^4$, since $\mathbb{o}=0$.

I would be thankful if someone corrected my mistake.

Comment: Note for intuition: dimension $0$ means a (discrete) collection of points, not that the intersection is empty. Consider two curves in the plane that generically intersect at a discrete collection of points $(1 + 1 - 2 = 0).

Comment: Also, it's easier to think in terms of **co**dimension in an ambient manifold: 
$\operatorname{codim}_M(L) = \dim M - \dim L$ for a submanifold $L \subseteq M$. With this notation, the generic (i.e. [transverse](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Transversality_(mathematics))) intersection is of codimension given by the simpler formula: 
$$
\operatorname{codim}_M (L \cap K) = \operatorname{codim}_M (L) + \operatorname{codim}_M (K)
$$